# Has Florida left 75% of its lettuce crop unharvested due to the coronavirus lockdowns?

Tags: united-states, economics, covid-19, statistics

Various sources claim that Florida's coronavirus lockdown has caused a serious breakdown in the food supply chain in the state.  For example, [this Politico article](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/04/26/food-banks-coronavirus-agriculture-usda-207215) states the following:

> The scale of produce waste is staggering. Farmers in Florida, which
>   provides much of the fresh produce to the eastern half of the U.S.
>   during the winter and spring, left about 75 percent of the lettuce
>   crop unharvested, along with significant portions of the state’s sweet
>   corn, cabbage and squash. Up to 250 million pounds of tomatoes could
>   end up left in the fields, according to the Florida Department of
>   Agriculture & Consumer Services.

However, I can't easily find these statistics on the FDACS website.  Is the exact amount of unharvested lettuce available directly from the FDACS or another government or industry source?

Comment: Leaving a crop unharvested is not the same as destroying it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks the article implies that the lettuce was directly destroyed, at least in some places.  "Toby Basore, a grower based in Western Palm Beach County, Fla., estimates his company disced somewhere between 8 and 10 million pounds of lettuce into the ground in recent weeks due to lack of demand."

Comment: That's one grower.

Comment: @DanielRHicks fair enough.  I agree with the edit to the question.

Comment: I think the claim is noteworthy regardless of this squabbling over "left unharvested" vs "destroyed". I've changed the title to match the quote.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is true. There have been similar problems in the EU, although perhaps not on this scale (yet). Spain has re-allowed their agri workers to return for this reasons IIRC (many in southern Spain live in literal shanty towns, and concern for them probably isn't high.) There was a BBC video on this, but it's hard to re-find video materials on their site.

Comment: Well, I found a different video by France24 on Spain (for anyone interested) https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20200421-focus-feeding-europe-spain-s-fruit-and-vegetable-workers-at-forefront-of-covid-19-crisis

Comment: This is a little confusing. Are we trying to find the exact percentage of lettuce being left unharvested ("Well, actually, it is only 68.2%, so the report is fake news")? Would that be an answer?

Comment: Or are we providing [lists](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/04/dairy-milk-pandemic-supply-chains-coronavirus-covid19-pandemic/) [of](https://english.mathrubhumi.com/agriculture/agri-news/farmers-dump-tomatoes-on-wayside-after-price-drops-to-rs-3-per-kg-1.4715708) [other](https://www.kcrw.com/news/shows/press-play-with-madeleine-brand/coronavirus-food-waste-grooming-late-night-tv/food-waste-farmers-covid-19) [waste](https://www.thatsfarming.com/news/potato-supply-chain-turned-up-side-down-due-to-covid-19) - which is generally a StackExchange no-no.

Comment: @Oddthinking I am mostly interested in getting the claim confirmed from a primary source.  The number seemed very high to me, so I am wondering if there was some kind of mistake.  If the real percentage is 68.2% instead of 75%, the other points made in the article would still be valid; but if it's only 7.5%, then the article is "fake news."

Comment: Just reporting a dead-end: [2019 USDA Vegetables report](https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/02870v86p/0r967m63g/sn00bf58x/vegean20.pdf), issued in February, only records Arizona and California (page 54). Is that because Florida's lettuce production rounds down to zero? That doesn't seem consistent with the originally quoted article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Tallahasee Democrat](https://www.tallahassee.com/story/news/2020/04/21/coronavirus-florida-florida-seeing-522-million-covid-19-crop-losses/2999906001/) and [Fruit Growers News](https://fruitgrowersnews.com/news/florida-522m-in-covid-19-crop-losses-and-importance-of-agriculture-aid/) both report this figure to be from a telephone survey of growers, "the Florida Seasonal Crop COVID-19 Impact Assessment", conducted on April 15. I am not seeing any more direct reporting of the survey results than this. It also does not appear that official data has been released at this time, or that such figures are reported on a regular basis.

[The USDA](https://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/) has lettuce data for acres planted and acres harvested for the state of Florida only for certain years, so it is unclear whether the more official data that may eventually be released will be sufficient to answer this question directly.